# Is it possible to convert part of the webpage to PDF using puppeeter sharp?

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

Is it possible to convert part of the web page to PDF using a HTML element by its name or ID in puppeteer sharp. If so please provide a example code. Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to convert a particular HTML element to PDF using its ID. i.e, partial web page to PDF rendering. For ex: converting a particular div element to PDF instead of converting whole web page to PDF.

Comment: No, you can't. You could take a screenshot and then try to make a PDF from the image.